# Mongodb Inner Join query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, inner-join

I am learning mongodb and nodejs and I have just found a difficulty to load data whose "id" was never mentioned in "old_id" of the data which follows it.

For example, for the collection below:

```
{
    "title": "example_001",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "001",
                "old_id": "null"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_002",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "002",
                "old_id": "null"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_003",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "003",
                "old_id": "002"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_004",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "004",
                "old_id": "null"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_005",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "005",
                "old_id": "001"
            }
        ]]
}
```

the expected resulltat is:

```
{
    "title": "example_003",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "003",
                "old_id": "002"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_004",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "004",
                "old_id": "null"
            }
        ]]
}{
    "title": "example_005",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "005",
                "old_id": "001"
            }
        ]]
}
```

I don't know how I can specify a filter which allows me to return the results above, this filter will be stored in a variable and inserted in the script below:

```
//let old_filter = {"$and": [{data: {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: {$eq: ["last_id","null" ] }}}}] };
let filter = ??? ;
db.collection("mycollection").find(filter, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function(error, results) {
    try{
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results.length);
      return resolve(results);
    }finally{
      db.close();         
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you exactly have like this :: `"data": [[{
                "id": "003",
                "old_id": "002"
            }
        ]]` !!! So data is an array of array ?? So in this doc :: `{
    "title": "example_001",
    "data": [[{
                "id": "001",
                "old_id": "null"
            }
        ]]
}` , Do you've any other array in data apart from `"id": "001"` or even any other object in first array where `"id": "001"` exists ?

Comment: Yes, data is an array of array. For the moment, I have just one array, in data, the original conception of my programm is developed for multiple array but for my need I will use just one array like this : "data": [[{ "id": "003", "old_id": "002" } ]]